# Convert columns into rows when importing .csv

Tags: r, excel, csv, dataframe

I'm looking for an efficient way to use read.csv (or an alternative) when reading a .csv file that has 100,000s columns and virtually a single row.

The file with this structure is extracted from MATLAB which seems to prefer to add millions of rows rather than columns. When opening the file in Excel it does not load completely so I cannot simply transpose.

The following works in r, still slowly, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

```
library(data.table)
dfr <- as.data.frame(t(fread('filename.csv')))
```

Comment: How about using `scan` if there is only a single row?

Comment: Try `data.frame(Col=scan('filename.csv', skip=1, what=numeric(), sep=','))` assuming that there is a header line (which we skipped by skip=1)`

Comment: Give some detail about your MATLAB structure (or cell array), and show how it is currently saved (the Matlab code), if you want some help on how to save it another way.

Comment: @akrun, your scan solution works for single rows, thanks! I guess I can do that twice for two different single row .csv files and then rbind() them.

Comment: Is that fast enough?

Comment: Haha, ah I'm not too fussy about speed. I'm happy enough that it works and it's a lot more efficient than read.csv which is what I was initially trying (and making my computer crash). So yes, thanks fast enough!

Comment: @Adriaan, thanks will go for the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only a single row, we can read it with `scan` and convert to `data.frame`

```
data.frame(Col=scan('filename.csv', skip=1, what=numeric(), sep=','))
```